# How do I see everything that a Ruby program is doing?

Tags: ruby

I have a program that has some kind of problem, so I would like some kind of debugging tool or something to tell me everything that my program is doing. Kind of like this:

> Set variable test to "test"
>
> Printed the value of test ("test")
>
> Added "2" to value of test
>
> Set variable test2 to value of test ("test2")
>
> Set variable test to "test"
>
> Printed the value of test2 ("test2")

Comment: Trace mode? Possibly too much information, though. How about just debugging it?

Comment: I tried debugging, but to me it didn't seem to be what I wanted. I'll check out Trace mode.

Comment: Tracing seems too cryptic to me.

Comment: Debugging is *precisely* what you want. Often you need nothing more than some logging and common sense.

Comment: Any debugging tools you could suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) to debug my Ruby on Rails application, but it's a gem that can work outside Rail. Just require it, write `byebug` somewhere in your code, and it will turn your Ruby interpreter into a debugger like gdb.

Answer (score 1):

[pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) is a great tool for debugging. It lets you set points (`binding.pry`) in your program which allow you to see more about what your program is doing, what variables are set to, etc.

Comment: I get an error when trying to install using `gem install pry`

Comment: ERROR: While executing gem ... <Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError> bad response Not Found 404 <https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.10.1-x86-minw32.gemspec.rx> (Hand typed that from my command prompt, might be slightly different)